# Solving for intersecting projectile motions

Tags: kinematics, projectile-motion

I have no idea how to start this, was thinking about the displacement would have to be the same but don't know where to go from there.

A cannon fires two missiles with speed $v_0$=250$ms^-1$, the first at angle $\alpha_1$=60 degrees to the horizontal and the second one $\alpha_2$=45 degrees. Show that for the missiles to collide in mid-air the time interval between the shots must be equal to:

$\Delta$$t$ = (2$v_0$/$g$)($sin(\alpha_1 -\alpha_2)$/($cos\alpha_1$ + $cos\alpha_2$))

Comment: A broad hint: both arcs are parabolas.  Write their equations in non-implicit form (i.e., write $y=f(x)$ rather than $x=x(t), y=y(t)$ - you can use the fact that $x$ is linear in $t$ to do this).  Consider where the two parabolas intersect (i.e., where $f_1(x) = f_2(x)$; this will be a quadratic equation - why?) and then figure out when each one will reach the point of intersection.

Comment: (Also: 'hard' for one person is not for another, and it's not generally descriptive of the actual question. I've edited your title to be a bit more descriptive without losing the essence of it.)

Comment: Ok thanks very much, i can work out from your hint the point at which they collide, but from that how do i show the formula?

Comment: please help i have no clue

Comment: nvm i got it thanks!